# Spring Boot Dependency only for Dependency Injection Features?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I just started a Compose for Desktop project with Kotlin. So there is no web stuff I am used to. This is why I did not use Spring stuff from the beginning.

However after a while I kind of miss dependency injection ;)

I tried to look for a spring boot / spring framework dependency that only has functionality like `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Autowired` etc. I was not able to find anything. This always was somewhat included into other contexts like **Spring-Boot-Web** etc.

So my question: *Is there a Dependency Injection Only library with spring?*

Comment: You can always apply [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/). You don't need a framework to apply DI.

Comment: Yeah I fell back to do it manually since the hassle with a framework somehow is not justified since I am not using any of the advanced features like MVC etc.